# toString method calling, reference LinkedList and achieving same output as Java 7 Automated tester

Tags: java, oop, linked-list, tostring

Creating new order
        Product(s): Big Phone
        Big Phone with no accessories and no charger: $200.00
        Product(s): Original Charger
        Big Phone with no accessories and original charger: $220.00
        Product(s): Case
        Big Phone with case and original charger: $240.00
        Product(s): Other Accessories
        Big Phone with case, other accessories and original charger: $300.00

The Creating new order part, I've already done a system.out.println statement.
 The products are in a LinkedList in another class. 
        So this is the LinkedList
        
        `public class Class1
        {
            public static final Category PHONE = new Category("phone", 1, 1);
            public static final Category CHARGER = new Category("charger", 1, 1);
            public static final Category ACCESSORIES = new Category("accessories", 2, 
            3);
            private Category[] categories = { PHONE, CHARGER , ACCESSORIES };
            private LinkedList products = new LinkedList();`

```
        public Class1()
        {
           products.add(new Product("Big Phone", 200.00, PHONE));
           products.add(new Product("Small Phone", 50.00 , PHONE));        
           products.add(new Product("Aftermarket Charger", 10.00, CHARGER));
           products.add(new Product("Original Charger", 20.00, CHARGER));
           products.add(new Product("Case", 20.00, ACCESSORIES));
           products.add(new Product("Other Accessories", 60.00 , ACCESSORIES));
        }
      public LinkedList<Product> products(Category category){
            for (Product product : products)
                if (product.matches(category))
                    return products;
            return null;             
        }
```

I have already done a public boolean matches Category category in a separate class and done Public String phone() in another class with a lookup pattern.
 The "Big Phone...." statement is a Public String toString that I've done under class3.
So 1st question is how would I call toString in my method that is in another class?
My method is

```
 Public class Class4 {
    public class createOrder { 
    System.out.print.ln("Creating new order")
    } 
    }
```

Secondly, how would I be able to reference my LinkedList into my createOrder method so I can match with the output.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Edited title to be better and clearer.